# Установить php7 на ubuntu 15.04

Tags: php, ubuntu

У меня vds работает на ubuntu 15
Туда поставил vestacp - клевая панель, но только встала она с php 5.6
а я хотел бы попробовать уже php7 говорят у него прирост в скрости 100%

скажите как его установить? надо говорят добавить какой то репозиторий
но в инете чет рабочего ничего найти не могу.

Comment: 100% прирост скорости это как моментально?

Comment: А ваше приложение (vestacp) поддерживает PHP7?

Comment: Да не мое это приложение - это панель управления сервером vds

Comment: "А ваше приложение (vestacp) поддерживает PHP7?" если не использовать старые фитчи типо mysql, а использовать mysqli или Pdo то любое приложение будет поддерживать. (это если переходить с пхп 5=>7). если (php 4=>7) требуется будет изгнать ссылки везде:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Делаем `aptitude search php` (нет aptitude, ставим).
Смотрим, если находим в списках пакетов `php7.0` радуемся, если там находится только `php5.X` плохо. (и давно все сидят на ubuntu 16, как насчет обновления?).
Если нашелся php7.0 то `sudo apt-get install php7.0` или `sudo aptitude install php7.0`.

Если нету в списках:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php-7.0
sudo apt update
```

Повторяем процедуру. (да я тоже слышал что пхп 7 быстрее, но насколько мне не известно.).

Comment: Подрубать левую ppa? Может сразу скачать `install.sh` с официального сайта пхп?

Comment: А на счёт обновления до 1604 согласен - эта ветака будет поддерживаться 5 лет, а не 9 месяцев, как обычные релизы.

Comment: "Может сразу скачать install.sh с официального сайта пхп?" какбы это линукс, тут никто ничего не качает из стороннего, только подключают репо(с опаской) и ставят из него софт. "эта ветака будет поддерживаться 5 лет" вы хотите пхп 7, а он в убунте 15 не появится в списках поддержимого по(мож и появится но не скоро).

Comment: обновить не могу) т.к. веста поддерживает только ubuntu 15.10

Comment: Обновил. Успешно. Скорость на парсинге xml реально выросла в 2 раза! Я рад доволен оч крутое обновление